# When is it acceptable to delete a post?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, vote-to-delete, rules, faq-proposed

*Question inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426208/moderators-started-to-pursue-users-for-their-bad-post-deletions/) as well as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426189/why-delete-a-reasonable-potentially-fixable-question-within-20-minutes-of-it?noredirect=1&lq=1).*

This applies to users with privileges to cast delete votes. In some cases, a post may be off-topic. Here's some situations:

- It's blatantly off-topic, and not salvageable
- It's off-topic, but salvageable, such as if the OP includes their code in the question vs. as a link
- It's nonsense, but doesn't rise to the level of warranting a red flag (R/A or spam)

When is it appropriate (or inappropriate) for high reputation users to cast delete votes, as opposed to waiting for [the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) to do it automatically?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-a-question

Comment: @toolic It has a comment stating "Early and often.", an answer that encourages quick deletions, and another one stating if it doesn't have value for the site, without a clear definition of that. While that question is fine, it is somewhat ambiguous IMO.

Comment: The crux of this discussion to me, at least as far as the argument under [this answer](/a/426210) is concerned, seems to be a difference of philosophy regarding delete-voting. Are delete-votes to be used "[early and often](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/249992)", or more as a last resort or escape hatch for extra bad content that should be immediately removed? My personal reading of the help center is more the latter, but clearly that's not universal or necessarily correct; whatever criteria comes out here probably needs to address that difference of opinion among voters.

Comment: @zcoop98 [Shog9 said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171763): "***Stop deleting stuff early if it's not egregiously bad.***" and later on [the Roomba was turbocharged as a solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513). The "early and often" may have had some merit in 2011 but by 2013 it apparently didn't. And that was a decade ago.

Comment: Close and down votes should be used early and often. Delete votes... Those need a more measured approach because they are awesomely hard to come back from.

Comment: And that leads to the other side of the problem. If I'm afraid to use down and close votes because I know certain users are online and the post will likely be deleted within moments of it receiving the third downvote and close vote, then I can't do my job right.

Comment: related FAQ-proposed on MSE: [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/997587), which honestly gives me whiplash with how much "aggressive" it is than [/help/privileges/trusted-user](/help/privileges/trusted-user), which is much much more conservative... great. now I'm confused.

Comment: Also [How long should I wait before deleting a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/how-long-should-i-wait-before-deleting-a-closed-question)

Answer (score 16):

This is already covered [within the help center](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

> ## Deleting questions
>
> Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions.
>
> ### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good
> answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator
> attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great
> answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; they
> can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another
> question.
>
> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the
> number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the
> question and all its answers.
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can
> vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when
> a post scores -3 or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted
> despite having lots of votes or for being new, please flag it for
> community moderator attention.
>
> You can view a list of posts with outstanding delete votes via the
> moderator tools delete tab.

My understanding of the disagreement is what "no lasting value whatsoever" means... however I don't understand the objections to that.

If something is of "no lasting value whatsoever", that means it is unsalvageable; it cannot be edited by *anyone including the op* in such a way that it'd have lasting value.

## What does "lasting value" mean?

It certainly isn't a higher bar than any of our existing close reasons, so really it just means can it be edited to no longer fit within any of our close reasons. It *doesn't* mean we, as users with the ability to delete vote, are suddenly the arbiters of long-term usefulness and should use these delete votes as extra downvotes. If it can be edited such that it'd be valid to reopen it, then it certainly doesn't rise to the level of hasty deletion.

Comment: I can't even come up with an example for hasty deletion being necessary. There's several cases where deletion itself is necessary, but hasty? Any situation that needs immediate action needs a red flag instead. Everything else isn't really time sensitive. Though I would argue, any case where the roomba won't delete it and it should be deleted (typo question with upvoted accepted answer) there'd be no harm in casting a delete vote, but there's no real need to rush to get 2 others to vote too. There is no harm to prevent, no impending crash,

Comment: I reserve my delete votes (on sites where I have them) for questions that have missed the site scope by miles. For example, I deleted a [question about Wendy's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=64225223#64225223) — very off-topic where it was asked and also very off-topic on SO, but not quite spam.

Comment: Fair, kinda like programming questions hitting mso or mse. On slower stacks, deletion becomes a bit more useful IMO, given things sit on the front page for longer.

Comment: Wow, that's **way** out of date, though. Is "merging" even still a thing?

Comment: i don't generally consider merging a thing, but it does exist. Most answers worth existing are tailored to the post their on and won't fit well with a merge (and usually are already covered on the target anyway)

Answer (score 16):

Notwithstanding what the Help Center says, I want to try to derive an up-to-date guideline logically, and offer some more precise guidelines.

> When is it appropriate (or inappropriate) for high reputation users to cast delete votes...?

When the question *cannot reasonably be salvaged*. This entails:

- Others cannot edit it into a form worthy of being reopened, while being confident of preserving authorial intent (*but if you can, you should just do so instead of voting to close*); **and**
- OP cannot reasonably be expected to edit it into a form worthy of being reopened, *even with clear direction from others*, without *fundamentally altering* the question; **and**
- The question does not contribute to a searchable, high-quality library *in spite of* being closed.

Let's look at the close reasons:

- **Duplicate**: Deleting these is low priority, because even when they do not function as useful signposts, they help indicate the importance of canonicals. Delete a duplicate if:

  - The title is misleading or not useful for search, and cannot effectively be fixed without more or less duplicating the title of another signpost; **and**
  - The question did not *already* attract useful (i.e.: that don't duplicate answers on the canonical) answers prior to closure; **and**
  - OP is not contesting the closure; **and**
  - a reasonable amount of time has passed (as a rule of thumb: enough that the question would be eligible for the Roomba if it weren't a duplicate).
- **Needs details or clarity / Not written in English**: This can almost always be salvaged in principle, even though OP might not be capable of it. Give OP a chance to communicate the same idea properly. It rarely happens, but there is not really any rush. These questions should realistically never be upvoted or locked. If they get reopen votes or an edit, they should not be deleted. So the only reason to delete them manually is if they received an upvoted or accepted answer before closure - otherwise, the Roomba will get them within 9 days anyway.
- **Needs more focus**: If this is along the lines of "how do I make a MMORPG?" then go ahead and delete it. The scope fundamentally can't be narrowed without altering the question. On the other hand, if it needs more focus because it's a multi-part homework question, just try to get OP to pick one part to ask about.
- **Opinion based / seeking resources**: The subjective stuff. Consider whether an objective metric can be extracted, whether the list of potential resources can be narrowed, whether it's actually necessary to ask for a resource in order to make sense of the question (e.g., just edit "what library can I use to do X?" into "how can I do X?").
- **Not about programming / belongs on another site**: This will rarely if ever be salvageable. Someone who really has a pure math question isn't going to be able to make a programming question out of it again - at least **not until after** getting an answer to the math question, trying to translate that into code, iterating the "identify an issue -> do debugging -> isolate MRE" process, etc. The end result of this is a **new** programming question that should be asked separately, not in the original spot. Do use your judgment, though.
- **Needs debugging details**: By definition, choosing this closure reason entails a belief that debugging details that would make the question acceptable *could exist*. If they couldn't, *you would have voted "not reproducible" instead*. Don't delete these until the 9-day mark. Try to get *answers* deleted first, since they're (in your assessment) trying to do the impossible, and thus can't possibly be useful.
- **Not reproducible or caused by a typo**: This is the counterpart that you would choose if the question can't be salvaged. Obviously we don't want to keep around questions where OP simply fat-fingered something; clearly there is no *actual* question underlying that. Similarly, if OP is *sincerely asking* why two and two don't make five (*idiosyncratic* logic error), there's no realistic hope of editing that into a question that could be helpful to others (even if someone else had the same bizarre thought pattern, it wouldn't be *searchable*). **However**, there are many simple errors that follow a common pattern, that experts will recognize over time (e.g., [failing to account for De Morgan's Laws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003), or [getting the indentation wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722) for languages where that matters, etc. It's important to recognize that these sorts of things are **generally not actually typos**; OP has misunderstood (or neglected) something *vital, easily described and explained, and reproducible*. Find or make duplicates for these instead.
- **Custom reason**: Uh... tell you what, if you can get two other people to agree that the question should be closed for a reason that isn't covered by any of the standard reasons, and it doesn't lead to a reopen war / Meta drama etc., maybe we'll cross that bridge when we get to it.