# Simple questions should not be automatically considered off-topic and deletion-worthy

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77181524/238704) recently and was somewhat stunned by the level of negative reaction to it. It asks whether there is a way to determine version information programmatically for a particular logging library. The question was closed as needing details or clarity, has so far garnered 8 downvotes, and 2 votes for deletion.

I can understand the downvotes because this seems like a question that a little bit of research could answer. However, by my understanding, it *is* on-topic and needs no more details to provide an answer.

How can the close and deletion votes be justified?

Comment: That question needs way more details. 273K is right, they can just use the arrow operator. The asker needs to clarify exactly how they're using it that it is causing a problem. Is there a reason they can't use method overloads? What about templates? Is this relating to a function or storing it in an object?

Comment: @vandench: why are those details needed to answer how to programmatically determine what version of the logging library is in use?

Comment: Because that's not the question. And if that is the question, then that needs to be _clarified_.

Comment: @vandench The question is, and I quote, "How do I programmatically find the log4cxx version I am using?"

Comment: That's the title. That's not the entirety of the question. If the body of the question is irrelevant, then it needs to be removed. Since it is there, it only raises more questions. Do they need to know at compile time or runtime? Do they simply want to know how to check the version, if so that needs to _clarified_? Are they asking how to also switch between using a pointer and smart pointer depending on the version? Is there a reason they can't just use the `LayoutPtr` typedef? There's a lot of elements of that question that need to be _clarified_ before it can be answered.

Comment: I do agree with you somewhere along the line. What is being said in this post is all true. It is just that the rapid closure and the fact that the post receives a decent amount of downvotes at the same time is very likely to prevent the ideal situation described by Karl Knechten (closed, question fixed, reopened) to happen. The combination of it all is such a loaded signal towards an unprepared mind. This aspect of the site just doesn't work, IMO. Too many crossed wires.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Closing questions does not mean they are off topic

It is perfectly acceptable, and in fact a vitally necessary part of the ordinary operation of the site, to close on topic questions. This happens when the question meets *any other* criterion for closure, including being unclear, unfocused or lacking in debugging details. (Of course, duplicates are also closed as duplicates, directly routing them to an existing answer.)

Questions that fail to meet standards *must* be closed as quickly as possible, so that people who *incorrectly* want to try to answer them (which *interferes with the normal working of the site*) don't get a chance.

**Question closure is injunctive, not punitive**. Preventing answers is the primary goal.

When a question is immediately closed, generally the OP [has at least 9 days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) to at least attempt to edit it (or someone else can cast a reopen vote regardless) before it gets deleted automatically. If the question gets a positive score, it will hang around for at least a year (this requires a +2 if the OP's account is deleted). It will furthermore hang around indefinitely if it gets at least two undeleted comments, which is usually the case (because people will comment to try to figure out how to fix the question).

Even supposing we ignore the questionable context for the problem described, the question remains whether OP is trying to figure out the version at compile time or at runtime; whether the code needs to do something at runtime based on that behaviour or if it will be used for some kind of build-time preprocessing, etc. These details need to be clarified. For that matter, depending on the answers, the question could be a duplicate. (For all I know, anyway. I don't know anything relevant about log4cxx, but I take @vandench's analysis for granted.)

### This question [should not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426214) be speedily deleted

It seems very likely to me that the question can be appropriately clarified. Communication will be needed to determine whether OP (a) has an XY problem; (b) cares about such a problem (**it is perfectly legitimate** to ask "how do I do Y?" **even if** you determine that the actual problem in your actual code is X - just as it is legitimate to ask *even if you did not personally encounter a problem at all*).