# Should I flag a discussion that is actually a bad question?

Tags: discussion, discussions-space

Discussions are a new feature on Stack Overflow, and I'm quite confused about how community moderation should work there. The tools are much more limited, and there are no guidelines about moderation within the discussions area.

One of the flag reasons is "Should be a question". When should I actually use this? For good questions that should be essentially "migrated" to the proper Q&A? Or even for terrible questions that would be immediately closed there? There isn't another fitting flag reason for these, and I assume the flag doesn't actually migrate but gives the mods choices on how to handle them.

So should I flag bad questions in the discussions area, do nothing with them or do something else?

Comment: *"I assume the flag doesn't actually migrate but gives the mods choices on how to handle them."* There's actually not a migration option; if it's determined that a Discussion "should be a question", it will be deleted, generally with a reply posted explaining that it should be reposted by the user as a question.

Comment: I saw a lot of terrible and sometimes completley off-topic questions too and flagged the as "should be a question", but wish there would be something like, "this is basically a question, but off-topic for SO and should be deleted".

Comment: This is the flag that I’ve been using, though it’s certainly awkward. It’s like clicking “looks ok” on a terrible audit but worse, because it results in the user being recommended to post it as a question without a staging ground or further guidance.

Comment: In several cases, I used the "something else" flag, because users obviously (ab-)used discussions to repost closed questions or draw attention to their questions. Worthwhile to look into the users profile, to figure out why they posted in discussions instead of posting a question.

Comment: From the outside, as someone who _hasn't_ used discussions (so take this for whatever it's worth), I personally wouldn't flag any discussions as questions unless they're actually a good fit as a question. I don't see any value in forcing folks to move away from their discussion ([by deleting it](/posts/comments/986453)) to... a question that will be closed. To me, the point of that flag seems to be "your question is a better fit for actual Q&A; it could benefit you and the community", which is obviously not the case for questions that aren't... good.

Comment: Put another way, it doesn't make any sense to me to send folks to a place where they will certainly fail. If the content is bad and unfit for discussions, and _also_ bad and unfit as a question, the correct avenue seems to be another flag or some other option, not sending crap to Q&A where literally no one will benefit (not you, not the author, not the community).

Comment: @RyanM I think that's worth writing up as an answer. That said, people who would post bad questions should be warned that it would be a bad question as is; and it shouldn't be moderators' job to identify why the question is bad.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't think I quite answered the question though; I just answered what (generally; it's not automatic) happens when a "should be a question" flag is found to be valid.  As to whether questions that should not be posted as-is should be flagged in that manner: I lean _yes_, because deleting only _good_ questions from Discussions and leaving only the bad ones seems like it's definitely the wrong approach.  But I haven't fully thought it through.

Comment: @jps IMO, if it's off-topic, it's off-topic, and the presentation form doesn't matter. I agree that "off-topic" is worth explicitly calling out as a separate flagging reason. (Also, I meant to integrate your point about checking for abuse into my answer, but couldn't figure out how.)

Comment: @zcoop98 "Put another way, it doesn't make any sense to me to send folks to a place where they will certainly fail" Excellent point. We've seen the same thing with attempts at migration from one main site to another.

Comment: Aren't all discussions started with a question? Does this mean we should flag all of them if we think they are "bad"?

Answer (score 13):

### tl;dr

The site has started workshopping this feature without a clear vision for why it's being added to the site. Going forward, depending on the intent, such posts should either simply be allowed to remain open (there's nothing wrong with them), or else flagged (but the reason doesn't seem to exist yet). **In the interim, flagging as "Should be a question" is probably okay** for [**salvageable**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426214/when-is-it-acceptable-to-delete-a-post/426219#426219) questions, because it is *not actually a migration option*. Naturally, if something is opinion-based, or asking for resources, then it *shouldn't actually be a question even if presented that way*.

### The status quo

Per Ryan M in the comments, moderators don't currently actually migrate discussions that "should be a question" - there isn't tool support for that. Instead, moderators will take action by just deleting the discussion, and possibly leaving a note with advice to repost as a question.

Of course, some questions are effectively unfixable, and their authors shouldn't be encouraged to do so. It would be nice for the interface to be able to distinguish the case of problems e.g. caused by a typo or which are answered by a duplicate Q&A. In these cases, it may make more sense - for now - to flag with a custom reason. Such attempts at "discussion" could be described as simply off topic in the discussion section.

Because discussion posts that "should be a question" are *highly likely* not to meet quality standards, I would like to suggest to the moderators that they should have a template for any such feedback, which preemptively warns about common problems with questions (lack of focus, improper MRE/specification) and links the appropriate help center documentation - including the tour and the how-to-ask page.

### Not rhetorical: What are Discussions for, anyway?

I can imagine two different motivations for adding Discussions to the site that could actually improve things:

1. Perhaps they are intended to provide the "discussion forum experience" that so many users expect and don't find, and *keep it away from the main question space*. This model could lead to a future where tags get their own "collectives" and corresponding "discussion spaces" automatically, the volume of new questions drops dramatically, a large fraction of "tumbleweed" questions (including very old ones) on the main site get converted into discussions automatically (and then mothballed if they still fail to go anywhere), and eventually the curation problem for the main site is solved indirectly.
2. Or perhaps they are intended to be a way to restore a "best of 2009 Stack Overflow", when the most popular questions were flooded with things that are today closed as subjective or seeking resources, but which touched on important topics with broad relevance to serious developers. In this case, we could migrate old "historial locked" questions (and questions that haven't been closed but *should* have that historical-lock status) to set positive examples for discussions, while avoiding the problem of people using those examples to argue on Meta for reopening their own new closed questions.

But **Discussions cannot be both of those things**. Questions of the second type *depend on* not drowning in questions of the first type to produce value; and no, sorting/filtering based on question score does not solve the problem, because it's a problem of curation policy and a problem of *setting a goal* for the feature.

If the goal was anything else, then I cannot in any way endorse adding Discussions to the site and would strongly encourage staff to cancel the experiment ASAP.

#### What if they really are a traditional forum?

**In the first case, there is no action to take** - the feature is being used as intended. If you look at a discussion and think "that looks like a bad question", the most likely reason it looks bad is because it hasn't been refined yet. (If it would be bad because it's "primarily opinion-based", *doesn't discussion make more sense than asking a question in a Q&A, anyway?*) Discussion could be a powerful tool for that refinement.

**Yes, that would be effectively reinventing the Staging Ground, *but*** in a way that I think is more likely to actually work. People understand the model of asking a "question" on a discussion forum. Most of them don't, apparently, have the same intuition for the idea of, essentially, posting a proposal for the question part of a FAQ entry, and then collaborating to improve it. Besides, asking a question well *often requires perspective lacked by* those who actually need it answered. If individuals get helped this way and someone with expertise notices a pattern in common problems, that can lead to posting a self-answered canonical.

**Yes, this would be duplicating a ubiquitous service, *but*** it seems clear that it could provide a very useful filter. I can even imagine a future where new users are restricted to Discussions by default, *but* the community can allow (either by explicit voting or some other system) users who post *good* questions (or just one) in the discussion space to have access to the main space.

#### What if they're still held to quality standards, but subjective?

If Discussions are still not meant to work like a traditional discussion forum, this first of all needs to be made a lot more clear. But I suppose that in this case, "bad question" discussions should be dealt with in more or less the interim way I'm currently proposing.

Comment: Option #1 for the "why" would essentially be to have a Subreddit space within the site - which I am all for to be honest, because the inevitable alternative is that the Q&A site itself transforms into it at some point.

Comment: @Gimby there's an argument to be made that most people have been treating the main site that way for years. People who actually understand and preserve the purpose of the site are in the minority, which is also related to why there is so much animosity towards them.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

That said, the wording of that flag reason is not very clear for a user flagging a Discussions post. As the question details very well, the flagging user doesn’t have any concept of what might happen. There is the implication of some kind of migration path, but that does not exist (and is not on any near-term roadmap).
I believe that a [restated question will better prompt the needed conversation, so I’ve asked that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428081). Please take a look!

To answer a question that’s implicit in the original post and explicit in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428039/18279858):

Two purposes of Discussions are to provide a lower-stakes and lower-stress place for users to contribute successfully, and to provide a space for users to learn and interact outside the defined scope of Q&A (as detailed [in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426143)). In both cases, these users may be more motivated to return and be active community members.

The experiment is being conducted with the intent of not disrupting Q&A. In the long term, we'd be looking at how this content format can help more fully meet the needs of both learners and those motivated to help others learn.

Discussions is a new area, surrounded by plenty of gray areas. While those gray areas will probably never fully disappear, we can work to reduce them in various ways. That’s one of the things we’re learning about now in this experiment stage.