# What should the Discussions flag reason “should be a question” be changed to?

Tags: discussion, discussions-space

### UPDATE: March 4, 2024

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429339/18279858) below details the updated to flag reasons that was informed by dialogue on this post.

---

This question is carrying on conversation and points from [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428035), but framing the central focus a little differently.

The flag reason “Should be a question” feels both inaccurate and misleading. The wording was crafted based on observation of Discussions in its early days. But now with the [recent expansion of the experiment to all tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427864), I think we need to reframe this reason to flag a Discussions post.

It’s helpful to clarify the user experiences of Discussions flagging as we consider this, and define what group this change would most impact.

- For the flagging user, they won’t know the outcome of the flag or receive feedback about whether their submission was considered helpful or not. While we can look ahead to more complete feedback loops in the future, for the purposes of this question we need to accept that status quo. So the wording of this option needs to speak to the curator mindset and make it clear what they are communicating to moderators.
- For moderators, they see the flag reason and the user who sent the flag. There is the general understanding that “this person believes this post is not right for Discussions” but any further intent behind the flag remains unclear.
- For post authors, they are unaware the post has been flagged. If the post is deleted, moderators are encouraged to post a reply right before the deletion, so that the author may follow the notification and see that response. Community Managers and Discussions moderators have developed some template replies for common scenarios. So ideally there is some feedback and advice for the author happening there.

The template text (noted in the third bullet) and the replies produced from it can vary depending on the scenario. And while it’s interesting to dive into what those replies might advise, that’s a separate conversation from the question posed here. But I’ll note that in most cases, if the author’s intent seems to be asking a question that’s appropriate for Stack Overflow Q&A, the reply advises them to review how-to-ask (and does not suggest taking the exact same post to Q&A).

tl;dr — the group we are looking to impact with this proposed change is the **flagging users**, the curators who work to keep things on the rails.

**Initial proposal:**

Considering the second bullet above, perhaps the flag reason should be renamed to something like “Does not belong in Discussions.” And perhaps the secondary text below the reason (refer to the image below) could say something along the lines of “If you have further feedback about this Discussions post, use the ‘Something else’ option below to give more detail”

[image: image of proposed flag modal for discussions posts that includes options for: spam, rude or abusive, should be a question, something else (with free form text field visible)]

Answer (score 5):

After conversations on this post and with Discussions moderators, later this week we expect to update the flag reasons modal in Discussions. The "should be a question" option will be replaced with "Not suitable for Discussions". The secondary text for this option will be: Use this option if the post is not a discussion, might be better suited for Q&A, or is very difficult to understand.

This should better address the intent of a flagging user who feels that the post "does not belong" without creating the impression that the post might be migrated elsewhere. This updated reason is also inclusive of scenarios where the post does not attempt to start a conversation or has unclear intent.

[image: Updated Discussions flag modal with the "Not suitable for Discussions" flag reason]*The updated Discussions flag modal*

Comment: Would this flag reason cover basic close reasons, such as not in english, or homework dumps with a "please solve by Friday" message?

Comment: @Fastnlight I think it would, since those scenarios have been common enough (at least in Q&A) to be familiar. So flagging users may know they don't need to provide more detail for those.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like, the primary reasons i would flag a discussion in this manner would be for:

1. The discussion, if asked as a question, would very likely be a duplicate with known good answers.
2. The discussion, if asked as a question, would be a valid on topic question (possibly with some additional details or different framing)

1 is fairly straight forward and would benefit from a link to the duplicate

2 is a bit more complicated, in that the user would benefit from some guidance in *what* details or different framing would result in a good on topic question.

Would leaving a reply after casting a flag in both of these cases be a useful follow up as the user casting a flag? or would that be more something that a mod should do once they've agreed with the flag and are on the path to deleting the discussion? Seems like it'd be kinda weird to pre-give that kind of advice as if the flag was already handled, only for the flag to potentially be declined.

Both of these cases could potentially be solved using your initial proposal, if the mod were to also follow up with a note to the user before deletion in each case.

Comment: I also kinda question whether 1 should even be an immediate deletion. There's no reason some discussion can't occur related to the duplicate once it is linked up.

Comment: To answer the your question (and also to the point of your comment above), if you flag using this reason and leave a constructive reply, write that without worrying about whether the flag is declined or the post is deleted (the author will be able to see the reply in either case). The reply you leave will likely be more specific than what the mod might leave, and if you're speaking from subject matter knowledge then it will likely be helpful for the author. If there's back-and-forth with the author, that's even better. And the whole thread could be an example for others considering posting.

Comment: After commenting on a few in this way, it actually feels pretty futile. It's the same advice to each one effectively, mightaswell just link them to the help articles that the ask wizard is already going to link them to. These questions are so low tier that they almost seem like someone trolling. Why should i expend so much effort to help someone ask an answerable question that at the end of the day is just yet another debugging question that will help noone even if it is fixed.

Comment: I'm sure there's someone out there that would love to help users in this situation solve their problem, but I *really* dont like the idea of having it be a place separate from Q&A, as then you're constantly going to have this battle of "does this belong on discussions or Q&A" , and often times it is only possible to know what is useful by letting time go by and seeing what people find useful. By the time we know a given discussion is useful in that way who do we encourage to create a real Q&A, given the OP is long gone and has their answer?

Comment: It's true that ultimately it should be the site itself helping users find the right place for their question/post. It's wonderful if someone, due to whatever motivation, takes the time to offer a suggestion to an author. But we can't and shouldn't count on that as the way the author gets help. For older posts where the dialogue might be worth summarizing/consolidating into a Q&A, perhaps there is a type of person to whom that activity is appealing. Perhaps that is even another type of flag to consider down the road (e.g. "This older post is a good candidate for migration/summarization")

Comment: "is a bit more complicated, in that the user would benefit from some guidance in what details or different framing would result in a good on topic question." Perhaps the OP could be led to an understanding of what's needed/missing by... *discussion*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yea, no.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That would be the purpose of Staging Ground. I am not a huge fan of discussions becoming a dumping ground for every poor question in existence. I mean there are some discussions which may start like two liners with people asking "where to start" but such discussions actually belong to discussions. If someone has a very specific problem then it is a most likely a question, not a discussion, even when they don't know how to write a good question.

Answer (score 4):

Unpopular opinion time: I think removing the flag and doing nothing else should be an option on the table.

It is going to be an inevitable reality that people are going to be making their home in the discussions feature and thus are going to want to ask/discuss ALL their questions through it, even if some of them just happen to accidentally comply with a QA knowledge based question format. Just like people are right now trying to force all their questions into the QA part of the site and losing their ability to post questions as a result of it - something I was hoping the discussions feature could actually help with. Even if signing up to multiple sites/services and asking questions on the right one is what responsible people should do, it is the path of most clicks.

Let me put it differently. Let's direct people from the knowledge base to the discussions feature and actually solve some problems that could right now only be solved by directing people to Reddit or Discord. We don't do the other way around, it is a one way street. Keep it simple. Certainly right now when the thing is still trying to learn what exactly it's purpose in life is.

Comment: I mean... mighatswell shut down Q&A while we're at it, no? quite obvious if one can choose between asking a question somewhere with no barriers vs somewhere where their question needs to adhere to quality standards and not be a duplicate that they'd choose option one every time. I don't disagree that the barrier of entry needs improvement and that there's a whole tier of questions being outright shut down currently at the helpdesk level that would benefit the site to be allowed and answered somewhere, but i don't see how making discussions that place allows the useful content to make it to Q&A

Comment: It's always good to ask "do we need this at all?" for this type of inquiry. Perhaps down the road we rename it again, or remove it entirely, or expand it into a set of sub-reasons (as with "needs improvement" on questions). Right now this option is here to help the flagging users feel that there is purpose and value in flagging a post and helping to curate the space. The value is added for the moderators & Stack Overflow as well, bringing specific scenarios to our attention as we observe the scope of what people want to post and adjust strategy accordingly.

Comment: I think that we shouldn't have a "this should be a question" flag. I've only seen incredibly low-quality questions in Discussions, and I think directing low-quality questions to Q&A is only going to result in us first having to flag the Discussion, then having to flag/close-vote the resulting Question.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that this is still in the positive after waking up. I flip what Berthold says. Right now, no migration path from discussions to QA and for the sake of not influencing anything no path the other way either. It is too new, people are still... flocking. Maybe later down the road when it is clear how people are going to be using discussions in the general sense can some path be opened up, either way. This is still experimental, let it experiment please.

Comment: "quite obvious if one can choose between asking a question somewhere with no barriers vs somewhere where their question needs to adhere to quality standards and not be a duplicate that they'd choose option one every time." - As someone who curates the site, staring at the pile of 24 million existing questions, this sounds like the exact opposite of a problem. Incidentally, did you know that it's [perfectly allowable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to *write* questions that you aren't actually *asking* (i.e. don't need someone else to answer)? If only that were the default.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Of course. I'm also aware people often abuse it to create *yet another* copy of an existing question that's been duplicated 1000 times in the name of creating a canonical, instead of picking an existing one and improving it.

Comment: Trust me: it's **common** that **every** existing version is **so bad** that writing from scratch is easier and produces a clearly superior result.