# Discussions: Learnings and experiments

Tags: discussion, downvotes, discussions-space, a-b-testing

The new [Discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions) space continues to take shape as more users discover it, reply to posts, and start new conversations. We are very thankful to the Discussions Moderators who are devoting time to managing the space and collaborating with the Community Team. Thanks as well to community members and Stack Overflow moderators who are participating and offering feedback.

Discussions provides a way for developers to learn or share a new perspective outside of the traditional question-and-answer space, with a lower barrier for engagement and covering a broader range of topics. Here are a few recent Discussions that have stood out as great conversations, with various perspectives being shared:

- [What are some uses of Enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77930002)
- [What inspired you to program?](http://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78094908)
- [How do you stay on top of what happens in the world of .NET, C#, Roslyn and co?](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77985063)

Below are details about recent changes and new experiments in Discussions. The goal of these efforts is to help users discover Discussions, encourage more contributions (both new posts and replies), and guide users toward making successful posts.

### Feature updates

The default sort on the [Discussions list page](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions%27) is now “Latest activity” instead of “Newest.” This allows active, older posts to be presented higher on the list at any given time, helping to balance out brand new posts that might not be as interesting to the community. An individual user’s selected sort option will still be retained for future visits. This change was released on February 28.

The right sidebar on Discussions pages will now feature a module that summarizes the guidelines, making it so users don’t need to visit another page to understand the basics. The full guidelines are linked in the top section of that module. This module can be viewed starting today on the Discussions list page, as well as the post display page and the post creation page. This update is effective today, March 7.

The flag reason “Should be a question” has been changed to “Not suitable for Discussions” to provide more clarity for users who are raising a flag. The secondary text for that option was also updated. Conversation on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428081/) and with the Discussions moderators was helpful in moving this change forward. This update is effective today, March 7.

[image: Updated Discussions flag modal with the "Not suitable for Discussions" flag reason]*The updated Discussions flag modal*

### Experiments

We’re looking at how to raise awareness of Discussions and prompt creation of new posts with **two A/B tests**:

- The “Discussions” item on the left navigation will move to display under “Questions.” This test launched on March 5 and is being presented to 5% of users.
- A “Start discussion” button will be displayed at the top of question pages next to “Ask Question.” This test will be presented to 5% of users and will begin as soon as data from the previous test reaches statistical significance. This is not a test of any proposed final design; it’s simply determining if this approach merits further exploration in the future.

For both tests, we’ll be looking specifically at whether more users click to start a discussion post (even if they do not end up publishing it).

We’re also making one change for all users as an experiment. For now, **we have removed the Discussions downvote function and removed downvotes from the Discussions post score calculation**. The reasoning behind this change is that there is not (yet) a clear shared definition of what a downvote means in Discussions.

Possible meanings of a downvote may be:

- This is a low-quality post
- I do not like the topic of this post
- I disagree with the sentiment expressed

All are valid, but the lack of a shared definition can mean that the scores are a confusing signal. The prompts at the bottom of this post relate to this subject – *what should a downvote in Discussions signify?*

To be clear, we’re not questioning the usefulness of downvoting, in general, as a curation tool. This experiment is specific to the new content format of Discussions. Without a clear sense of what a downvote in Discussions signifies, users may (understandably) be applying norms and standards from Q&A. By removing downvoting, we are:

- Allowing space for norms and standards for Discussions to evolve
- Exploring how user interest in Discussions (as a whole) might be affected by only showcasing upvotes

Removing the downvote option encourages users to *express concerns* about a post via flagging and to *provide constructive feedback* (ways the post might be improved, etc.) by replying. If the absence of downvotes results in more flags and replies, that’s not a bad thing. With the accompanying update to the flag reasons (mentioned above), this should result in more informative curation.

This change affects all existing and future discussion posts. We’ll primarily be looking at post creation rate, number of replies, and post success rate (i.e. whether or not it is ultimately deleted) as we consider the effects of this change. Below are some questions about downvoting in Discussions, and we’re interested in your thoughts.

Reminder: Voting in Discussions has never affected user reputation

**What should a downvote communicate in Discussions? Might that signal be better sent via private flag or public reply?**

**Can the upvote count alone communicate quality (consider the significance of no upvotes, versus one upvote, versus 10 upvotes)?**

Comment: "Possible meanings of a downvote may be" So what does an upvote mean, then? It looks like all three categories could equally well separately apply for that direction too.

Comment: What clear signal does upvoting provide, compared to downvoting? I generally think voting at all on discussions isn’t useful. The activity alone should be enough of an indicator.

Comment: I downvote spam posts and AI generated replies. Posts that I've seen receive downvotes are people trying to draw attention to their question (either linking or copy/pasting their question in discussions), and stuff that is prohibited on the main site (such as people thinking we will solve their homework/do their job for them). Just like the main site, one of the primary functions of downvotes is that they indicate **lack of effort or is unclear** (expressed in the hover tooltip). They are also used for **posts that break the rules** (such as spam and other prohibited content).

Comment: @KevinB No voting at all is certainly a scenario to consider as well. What are you referring to when you say "the activity"?

Comment: currently, just replies, or how active a given discussion is, etc. If a discussion is attracting a lot of replies, then it's clearly something that is either controversial or interesting, both of which warrant more views/discussion

Comment: Here's an example of a discussion that should be downvoted: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78123938/i-have-a-important-question This user used a discussion for the sole purpose of advertising their question.

Comment: @Fastnlight i think those two are examples of things that should be flagged. Downvotes aren't the right tool for having things deleted in discussions

Comment: @KevinB That is correct (and I did flag it). I also would have downvoted it to let other users know that it was not a discussion, but more of an ad

Comment: I guess another way to look at it, as far as the activity bit, what are people looking for when they want to participate in a discussion? I'd expect to be recently active, more so than highly active in the past but no replies in a month. The last activity filter covers that

Comment: @Berthold I mean this well, but... I'd suggest that whoever decided to remove downvotes reads [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/16886597) by Shog9, and specifically the section *The value of downvotes, at last*. While some of it isn't directly applicable, I do feel that the broader sentiments are closely related. Specifically, the points about introspection and the possibility of a "dump" of a list of issues with a post as a reply.

Comment: I feel that whoever is making these decisions is taking the easy way out. "What is XYZ supposed to mean?" -> "Hmm, I don't know let's just keep it out for now." The same thing was done with [flag outcomes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427499) and the same is being done here. Rather than doing this it would be better to simply **talk to the community** to figure out what things should mean. Stack Overflow the company seems to be following a process where they are only looking at how they believe the site should work rather than engaging the users and asking them.

Comment: The approach being followed in this case seems to be "Let's remove things and then collect feedback on why it should be added back" rather than "Let's ask the users whether a particular feature should be kept or removed". The post is titled "Discussions learnings" but I see very little information (other than basically three "good examples") about what kind of content is found interesting by users and what kind of content is being downvoted / deleted, etc. As part of a new feature I'd expect that to be part of the learnings.

Comment: "What should a downvote communicate in Discussions?" - I don't know. What are the limits of discussions? If I take it as a general "discussions are essentially Reddit posts", then you hardly need voting at all. It'll be the same as voting on meta - random and confusing.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'd debate your characterization of the approach we're taking. Discussions, as a whole, is an experiment with a new content type for Stack Overflow. The voting (while using the same UI elements) is different than Q&A voting, since reputation is not involved and the content being voted on is not necessarily objective knowledge content. Which is all to say, this is something new that we're all observing and learning about together. We'll continue that as we see how things unfold with this latest change. (1/2)

Comment: It's not "Let's remove things and then collect feedback on why it should be added back", it's "Let's change something and see what happens, since this is something new and no one knows for sure what will happen." In other words, we're experimenting. Speculation about abstract ideas with a small group can only get us so far; we learn much more by putting something tangible in front of a much larger group. And we're talking with the community about it (you are part of that conversation right now!) and getting feedback alongside the experiment. (2/2)

Comment: Removing downvotes takes away the primary mechanism of quality control, and basically turns the site into a low-quality spam dump like Quora. Discussions was already worthless, but at least with negative scores, it was possible to identify and avoid poor-quality posts, which is most of the content on the site. Without downvotes, it's still low-quality, but without any indicator as such. Please keep these experiments isolated to discussions rather than apply them to the main network sites.

Comment: Have you removed the downvotes or just took away the downvote button for now? I still see discussions with negative score.

Comment: @M-- they're "hidden", and we can't cast them. it's a reversible change

Comment: @KevinB a couple of days ago, the downvote button was gone, but the score was still showing negative (at least for the examples I listed on my answer). Now, it's all positive. I am aware that it is reversible (per Berth's comment under starball request).

Comment: @M-- yes that was an error that occurred with the roll out, it has now been resolved.

Answer (score 48):

Downvoting means "I think this should be less visible". Replying instead of downvoting is counterproductive now that you're making active discussions more visible. Without downvotes, there is no way to correct the "hotness" algos that equally promote posts that have a lot of engagement because they're interesting and posts that have a lot of engagement for negative reasons.

Answer (score 43):

Currently, as of today, there's no way to indicate that a given discussions is ridiculous/useless, or poorly defined, besides replying.  This feels wrong, but I don't really know why. It's one thing for pointless chatter to exist in, say, a chatroom, but discussions are treated more... "officially" than chatter in a chatroom is.

Take [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78104620/update-cant-we-think-of-a-better-name-for-coding-seems-to-be-resolved) for example, *Can't we think of a better name for "coding?"* there is literally no value in this discussion existing here. It isn't an interesting discussion, it doesn't solve anything, it doesn't remotely approach a useful topic. Yet... by all available metrics it's one of the "most interesting" discussions that the discussions feature has attracted. If anything, it "should be a question" on another stack.

On top of that, the OP has edited it, and... we still don't have any ability to edit existing discussions that we haven't created. They've effectively used an edit to "resolve" it (incorrectly, lol), are we supposed to flag such bad edits?

Comment: I guess, in a sense, my concern generally is that there's a lot of highly upvoted discussions that just aren't.. useful. The best this, the best that, why you started programming, none of this is "useful" from the perspective of creating a useful knowledgebase of content. it serves no purpose outside of being a place to "discuss" things that otherwise would be closed as a Q&A pair. What problem is this feature solving? What purpose is it serving *well*? Why should it be promoted as a place for visitors to go to and use?

Comment: *" none of this is "useful" from the perspective of creating a useful knowledgebase of content"* - but is that the goal of discussions? I just don't know. We already had the Q&A site to fulfil that goal and discussions are strictly forbidden on it because they are not useful for a knowledge base. So I have to assume that now that discussions exists as a separate function, it also serves a separate goal. To compete with Reddit, no doubt.

Comment: @Gimby yea, that's sorta what I'm getting at. To me most of these discussions just look like nonsense. Not even things that'd be mildly interesting in chat. If the only value it brings is it existing as one more place for people to click... seems like a vanity project in a time when there's so much more that could be getting done.

Answer (score 27):

I for one want downvotes in discussions back.

Yes, even on ones cast on discussion posts I wrote.

For replies, it's a way to signal that I find the reply to not be useful, or that I disagree. For top-level posts, it's a way to signal that I find the discussion problematic in ways that are not necessarily flag-worthy (or that are). To put it honestly and bluntly, it means "I hope fewer people see this".

So yes. The possible meanings of a downvote that you listed are pretty much exactly what I inferred them to be (all three being valid), and I don't think most anyone else will have issue coming to the same understanding automatically. It's a pretty natural way of thinking. Just [put it back already](https://youtu.be/z286f9gAGvE?t=48).

Sorry for the cynicism, but my immediate suspicion was that this was "turned off" because a bunch of discussion posts are of terrible quality, or break discussion guidelines, and a bunch of things had negative score, which looks bad on the company / on the feature.

---

> Removing the downvote option encourages users to [...] provide constructive feedback (ways the post might be improved, etc.) by replying. If the absence of downvotes results in more [...] replies, that’s not a bad thing.

No, I think that *is* a bad thing. Then you get actual discussion and meta discussion in the same channel. That's a bad design. This is pretty well established. Meta commentary does not go in posts on Q&A. Some can go in comments. This is why the review queues including the task for deleting posts answers that are just commentary on other posts, and rejecting edit suggestions that are attempts to reply.

If and once constructive feedback gets addressed, that reply thread is just useless. And then what? We flag it? For a very small set of discussions mods to clean up? Enjoy the scaling problems. See also [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/11107541).

---

I was kind of neutral when discussions was announced, though [I thought a lot of the motivation for it was wrong](/a/426152/11107541) (I want to say "misled", but how does a company be misled about how its own flagship thing is supposed to work?). Then it launched and I gave it a try and posted about two things that I'd always wanted to write about, but felt wouldn't be smiled upon as SO Q&A. It was not bad. Honestly, I was pretty satisfied. Though the rest of the discussions space on average was and is pretty much a wasteland. I still find it highly annoying and problematic that I can't edit other peoples' posts to fix typos, and make their titles not suck.

Now I can't even signal when I think something is bad. Much of what interest I had in the space is gone.

Comment: "I still find it highly annoying and problematic that I can't edit other peoples' posts to fix typos, and make their titles not suck." – Agreed. (That was one of the nice things about having mod powers, as a CM... I could clean up the spaces around me, and make them better for everyone.)

Answer (score 15):

Removing downvotes is far from ideal. We talked about [downvotes research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399848/downvotes-research-why-do-we-need-that); I would suggest experimenting with some of the ideas there, instead of taking away downvotes. I would say capping downvotes for the OP to 0 or -1 (or even capping it for everyone for that matter), although still problematic, would do much less harm. Dropping all the downvotes altogether will have a negative effect on moderation and much more. Dalija explained in [one of the comments under their moderator nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15#comment137686586_78088023) why downvotes matter:

> ... downvotes help in removing such content and sending signal to others that there is something wrong with the particular post

---

##### Why all the downvotes?

We have a list of reasons here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/ While this was not developed with Discussions in mind at the time (there was no Discussions), there are some overlaps. Even if the differences between how we should use our downvotes on the main site and Discussions are dramatic (I'd say they are not), changing habits of the users to treat a portion of the site differently from the rest, is not as easy as one might think. It needs time more than it needs experiments. But putting that aside, let's look at some examples.

- [PDF merging - what is the current accepted solution for later versions of PHP (8 and above)](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78094453/pdf-merging-what-is-the-current-accepted-solution-for-later-versions-of-php-8) (as of March 4, there were 1 upvote and 4 downvotes): This seems like a legit discussion, in my opinion. If there was a review queue for Discussions, I'd either "Skip" or selected "Looks OK". So, I am not sure why that is downvoted (I know very little about PHP, so I should "Skip").
- [Best way of storing Http Request IP related infos](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78016627/best-way-of-storing-http-request-ip-related-infos) (as of March 4, there were 2 upvotes and 4 downvotes): The first response (XY problem) is probably the reason for most of the downvotes. That said, I'd have downvoted this on Q&A site, but on Discussions, ***I*** may have left it alone (no upvotes or downvotes from me).
- [PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.2 upgradation!](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77989033/php-7-4-to-php-8-2-upgradation) (as of March 4, there were 4 upvotes and 16 downvotes): This is way too broad, even for Discussions.
- [Discussion about Android SDK development](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77844240/discussion-about-android-sdk-development) (as of March 4, there were 3 upvotes and 11 downvotes): It is unclear, broad, not very well written, etc.
- [Laravel Learning](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77730746/laravel-learning) (as of March 4, there were 6 upvotes and 13 downvotes): This is a prime example of what you'd google. Then, if you were stuck between couple of options and had somewhat specific questions, I guess starting a discussion would be fine; but with no research whatsoever, I won't be shocked if there were more downvotes.
- [Adding Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) to the R interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77526179/adding-profile-guided-optimization-pgo-to-the-r-interpreter) (as of March 5, there were 4 upvotes and 6 downvotes): This is a well written post, it is just posted to the wrong place (as Dirk noted). We would also not accept issues about libraries and packages to be posted to Discussions (corresponding GitHub repository is the right place for those).
- (Bonus post): [Which R is the "best": base, Tidyverse or data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77085087/which-r-is-the-best-base-tidyverse-or-data-table) (as of March 6, there were 39 upvotes and 28 downboters): This is a "controversial" topic. You can tell that by looking at the replies. Nonetheless, I think this is a well-crafted post and do not agree with the replies which fail to see any value in that discussion. All that said, I think +11 is the right score for this. It is viewed positively, but not overwhelmingly positive (+39 score would suggest the latter).

---

> ..., but the lack of a shared definition can mean that the
> scores are a confusing signal. The prompts at the bottom of this post
> relate to this subject – what should a downvote in Discussions
> signify?

Downvotes are a *clear* signal about the quality of the posts and discussions. Out of all the examples provided above, I only was not able to justify one (and that is only me; there could be reasons that I've missed). So, I am not sure what's the issue that we are trying to address here. This experiment is problematic as I explained above. [It won't tell us anything that we don't already know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406806/6461462). We already know why we need downvotes to curate the content and, more or less, we know what should be downvoted and why. It is a bit cloudier in case of Discussions, but *clear* enough for many users. And, to arrive at a consensus and establish clearer standards, we can only wait and give this more time. I'd say taking downvotes away would actually slow down that process.

> Removing the downvote option encourages users to express concerns about a post via flagging and to provide constructive feedback (ways the post might be improved, etc.) by replying. If the absence of downvotes results in more flags and replies, that’s not a bad thing. With the accompanying update to the flag reasons (mentioned above), this should result in more informative curation.

I'd argue that it's not encouraging but forcing users to either flag/leave comments or simply leave the problematic posts alone. I mean, shall we start demanding comments when downvoting on the main Q&A site? (see [Why isn't it required to provide comments or feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436))

> What should a downvote communicate in Discussions? Might that signal be better sent via private flag or public reply?

The standards are different in Discussions. I think we can all agree on that. But the meaning of downvotes is not that different. If a post is downvoted, it is probably not up to the standards. If this experiment is trying to establish a strict global standard, I'd say that is some wishful thinking. We don't have that golden rule after almost 16 years on the main Q&A site.

Flagging and leaving comments, in some cases, are more effective than downvoting. But that does not mean downvotes are ineffective. Everything has a use case. For example, If one is downvoting because, and only because, there are a couple of typos in the post, it would've been better if they've left a comment (this arises another issue; let *"us"* edit Discussions). What about spam or rude posts? Yes, flagging is not only better, but necessary. However, there is nothing wrong with downvoting those too. Or what if someone already left a reply and explained the issue with the post. Should I leave another comment saying the exact same thing?! Well, I can also upvote that reply but with the current default sorting method (older first), even if that reply gets 100 upvotes, it can be stuck at the bottom (while for seeing the post score, I don't even need to visit the page).

> Can the upvote count alone communicate quality (consider the
> significance of no upvotes, versus one upvote, versus 10 upvotes)?

The composite score is **obviously** useful. As I said above, I can see that score without visiting the discussion while to see the comments I need to go to the discussion and scroll down. And flags are only visible to mods. Let's look at the example discussions again. All of these downvoted discussions also have upvotes on them. But they may not be as useful as the discussions with score of 0 (0 upvote/0 downvote). With this experiment you'd rank these "not so useful discussions" above the ones that just didn't get as much attention.

Answer (score 8):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Please at least tell me that the downvotes that were cast before this change are still in the database, and that they will come back into effect when you bring downvotes back.

Comment: Yes, all downvotes are still there and this is a reversible change.

Answer (score 8):

> Can the upvote count alone communicate quality (consider the significance of no upvotes, versus one upvote, versus 10 upvotes)?

The answer is a "no" and I would have thought it is very obvious. However, since you asked:

When the negative is removed from the scoring system, then we get a 1-dimensional score. Which cannot really be useful for comparison. Something can have more upvotes than something else because:

- Many people like it.
- Fewer people (percentage-wise) like it but it is older.
- It is more popular/visible than the other.

There is no way to tell with a 1-dimensional system. Moreover, any comparison between the scores of two topics is almost always going to be flawed. Yes, I used "almost always", so some times it might actually be a useful indicator. But 1. rarely 2. there would be no way to tell from the numbers alone.

With a downvotes count things will be different. A +30/-20 = 10 score should be a lot more different than a +10/-0 = 10. The former obviously has issues that have attracted 20 downvotes. Yet, with the 1-dimensional system you get 30 vs 10 and you are asking whether the 30 is clearly better.

Yes, you can point out "but it also means 30 people found it useful". However, upvotes are given out a lot more freely. Moreover, consider age - the score above do not rely on which was posted when to try and determine what an upvote would mean. One of the posts might be a year old, the other three years old. And it does not matter which one is which, the scores are still comparable:

- if try to compare a 3 year old post with score of 30 vs 1 year old post with a score of 10 it would *seem* they are about equal. Perhaps in 2 more years the score will climb from 10 to 30
- if you compare a 1 year old post with a score of 30 vs 3 year old post with a score of 10 it would *seem* the first one is way better. It has been up for less time and has gotten more score

This is what happens when the downvotes are removed. Pretty much all comparisons break down. And what you want to call "quality" actually just turns into a popularity meter.

Comment: technically it's two dimensional if you consider time (when each vote is cast), right? which is how you get things like "trending" sort options.

Comment: @starball you *have* to add other dimensions to derive any useful comparisons. SE's proposal is for upvotes to determine quality which they can't. A one dimensional score is meaningless. But age isn't even a great dimension. Votes only tend to go up with time. But without a downvote track you don't really see a good trend. If a post got 30 upvotes but overtime only accrued downvotes, that is different from starting at -20 and getting 30 more upvotes. Or any other mix.

Comment: for the record, I'm not disagreeing with your main point :P just nitting

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the majority of new discussions are actually questions.

- (How To question) How to delete page breaks from a WORD document (in c#)
- (Error Debugging) AttributeError: 'EasyEnsembleClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_resample'
- (Are Machine Learning questions even on topic here?) factoring the impact of uncertainty variables in construction projects
- (How To question) vertex-ai-pipeline
- (How To question) Flutter Chat App Through Flutter_webrtc
- (How To question, but possibly off topic for SO) Video Summary generation using DL models

These are all just from the first page that aren't yet deleted. How to questions have historically been the most useful type of question on SO, and here we are just allowing them to be dumped into discussions in a low quality format. I'm sure there's some people who are happy that how to questions they'd rather not exist are being effectively posted directly into the dumpster-fire that is discussions, but if you want discussions to actually be a place for *discussions* and not just lazy questions... maybe do something about it? We can't even downvote them anymore and none of the flags cover low quality/frivolous/off-topic or otherwise just terrible topics.

Comment: Just flag as not suitable, they will get deleted ;)

Comment: @M-- I think the point here is that the company has done nothing to stop such not-discussions from being posted. We already have the onboarding problem with the main site. Apparently after learning nothing from it and thus doing nothing about it, SE have just introduced it into Discussions. With the excuse that it's a growing platform that needs to find its own way but that's a bit like putting flower and eggs on the same table and waiting to see what kind of cake would emerge. Without direction and effort, the answer would be somewhere between "none" and "extremely disappointing".

Comment: @VLAZ that was a joke, I just meant I will take care of them, not that Kevin's statement is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

**Please disable the upvote option immediately while downvotes are also disabled.** There is no valid reason not to do so.

> What should a downvote communicate in Discussions? Might that signal be better sent via private flag or public reply?
>
> Can the upvote count alone communicate quality (consider the significance of no upvotes, versus one upvote, versus 10 upvotes)?

Frankly, if these are supposed to be *discussions*, why even have voting on them? Just let people discuss things. Provide adequate search capabilities, categories, and tagging features and editing/flagging/closing features and just let people discuss without trying to gamify that. This space has already been solved, exhaustively, by traditional forum sites decades ago; there's no shortage of forum designs that can be emulated here, like letting what's "hot" or "popular" be determined by the number of views, recent views, replies, etc.

Discussions are *not* Q&A. They are a new product; users need not expect or rely on similar interaction options as Q&A (like voting). For open-ended, opinion-based **discussions**, voting never really made sense in the first place. Especially if it's not tied to any user reputation (which was the entire point of adding voting to Stack Overflow Q&A in the first place--to give the post authors reputation to signify their knowledge and effort on the site, and then also to unlock site privileges).

Answer (score -6):

The very notion of *votes* in discussions (i. e. without any particular goal like Q’n’As) is ridiculous. Please add **emoticons** like in the *git laboratory* instead. You can click on a button and select from emoticons like    ☹  and the number of individual emoticon “votes” can be shown instead. This form of feedback is way more explanatory than a plain number could ever be.

Comment: We talked about this, and ... No, thank you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction/398410#398410

Comment: @M-- Thank you for referencing said discussion. I was not aware of that. Apparently, however, the discussion you mention was concerning the question‑answer format. The new “Discussions” feature does not follow a Q’n’A‑format, so maybe we can re‑discuss this suggestion regarding _this_ “Discussions” format?

Comment: I generally think reactions are better suited to discussions than Q&A, but, i disagree that emoticons are somehow more... "explanatory" than a plain number. None of those express any universally agreed upon "emotion", nor do they indicate anything about the post that they're left on.

Comment: I can agree that reactions are less harmful in discussions, but cannot say they are benign/useful in general, discussion or Q&A, nor more effective than the voting system.

Comment: Is that ok gesture genuine or sarcastic? What it does it mean when someone "raising hands"es my discussion? At least votes are unambiguously positive or negative.

Comment: @M-- To be fair your linked post is about reactions on Q&A, not on discussions. I don't think there's really much applicable about the concerns there to the topic of Discussions (other than that emoji reactions are, in general, not particularly useful as aggregate signals).

Comment: @TylerH to be clear, I specifically linked to my answer on that post, not the question. And as I said, in my second comment, I think emojis are less harmful in discussions, but that does not make them better than voting. I have already tried using emojis on SOfT and it just doesn't sit right with me. Kevin's comment says it all more eloquently.