# "Start Discussion" button on small screen is causing a lot of whitespace

Tags: bug, design, discussions-space

There seem to be a new <kbd>Start Discussion</kbd> button next to the <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button that is being wrapped below, causing even more unnecessary white space on the header.

---

I'm aware mobile support is dropped, but this could also accure on small desktop windows.

[image]

Comment: " but this could also accure on small desktop windows" - When you have a desktop window THAT small, you should accept that things are going to be shifting around.

Comment: Agree, but why aren't they in a row, there is more then enough space to display them next to each other!

Comment: Mobile support is dropped? I know the apps are gone, but as far as I know the mobile version of the site is still supported.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery the site is still supposed to work on mobile, I don't know what OP is referring to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addition of the button is a short A/B test that is running, noted on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429377). So this is not a permanent addition nor is it visible to most people. Thank you for detailing the layout issue on mobile, that has been noted.

**UPDATE March 15 2024:** This has been fixed.