# Rule proposal: Duplicate closure to roll-up questions is no longer allowed

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, rules

There is a long-festering problem in some tags where some questions are closed by dupehammers, using a single roll-up question as the duplicate target. A "roll-up" question is defined here as a question trying to cover multiple minor topics within one question and a set of answers. So [this Java question about null pointer exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) does not qualify, as it is about a single topic.

A prime example would be [this regex roll-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) which has [a large number of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/22937618?lq=1). This was [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate).

> Questions that are clear duplicates, but you can't find one quickly.

To be fair, PHP and other tags have such roll-ups ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-guide-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php-php-syntax)), and I have participated in hammering them as such. And there are a lot of questions that are low quality, where the temptation is to simply close them as the duplicates of the roll-up. I mean, it answers the question, doesn't it?

The problem is that this has started to promote two undesirable community actions:

#### Lazy closure

Dupehammers are a "one and done" action. Moreover, there is a belief is that these questions answer all the "core" elements and are therefore "useful" in low quality situations. The question for regex theoretically covers all symbols used within, so why isn't that useful? But this type of closure assumes that the roll-up covers all cases. The danger of dupehammers has always been that the target question doesn't really cover a specific use case. Lazy closure doesn't even bother to find that out first. Thus it becomes the action of choice for dupehammer users. It's problematic, but the community largely self-regulates this so it's not been a major issue. A low quality question can be closed for many other reasons beyond duplicate.

#### Tag gatekeeping

This action is the more problematic one. What we've been seeing for some time are "brigades" (for lack of any better term) of users who are committed to ensuring that only questions they see fit in a tag are open. Thus we get a number of these:

[image: Dupehammer 40000]

What this has turned into is not laziness, but deliberate actions, where we see the same users doing this over and over. Or, to quote a comment under the question I got the screenshot from

> I invite readers to examine the earlier question and ask themselves if any question could possibly be a duplicate of that question. If the answer is "no", please vote to reopen (and leave a comment giving your reasons for doing so). Closing this question, in this way, is sending a clear message to Peter, the OP (the polite version): "get lost". This catch-all closing of questions having a "regex" tag must stop.

I don't know that it sends a "get lost" message, as much as it sends another message moderators have been fighting against for years: RTFM. What these roll-ups have become, in essence, is another "fine" manual for users to read. Duplicate closure like this is basically throwing a volume of information at users and telling them "Figure out what, in this giant pile of information, answers your question." That's not useful.

It also effectively acts as a veto for anything any dupehammer user sees fit to close it as. Roll-up questions worked well as a philosophy for a long time, but (as the old saying goes), this is why we can't have nice things.

#### The rule

The rule would be as follows:

> Roll-up questions are useful in general, but may not provide enough guidance to users with specific questions, and serve as poor signposts to users looking for specific answers. Please use only specific questions for duplicate closure.

#### FAQ

- Moderators would enforce this new rule. No system changes would be made.
- Moderators would find out about violations via flags. Moderators already get an autoflag for closure disputes, and users could flag instances of this rule being violated.
- Enforcement would follow standard enforcement: A warning on the first offense and suspension for subsequent violations.
- Any other duplicate closure would still be allowed. If someone feels strongly enough that it's a duplicate, they should go find that specific question. Moderators [will still not solve duplicate disputes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419709/2370483), but the list of roll-up questions isn't long, and it's a fairly objective standard to enforce.

Comment: Assuming this idea gets traction, why not also close the known roll up questions as "Needs more focus" and/or lock them with a historical lock?

Comment: @RobertLongson Maybe. We'll see where consensus falls.

Comment: There are many questions that are exact duplicates of this. Closing or locking the duplicate target wouldn't be so good. Generally, I think most duplicate closures are ok. When users close unrelated questions using these targets, we already step in.

Comment: _Please use only specific questions for duplicate closure_. - so, no roll-up use for dupes? When would you use them? As guidance for users alongside other close reasons? Starts to feel like they would be considered as teaching / reference materials. (Then I would expect something like Robert's lock suggestion).

Comment: If "roll-up" needs to be [clarified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/427530/2) in terms of a question and a discussion about a proposed rule (which it does), then wouldn't the clarification be more useful somewhat prior to the penultimate sentence?

Comment: might be worth explicitly clarifying that this has nothing directly to do with [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/), which is a JavaScript module bundler. I personally was quite confused when I first saw the title of this meta post.

Comment: I'd have called this "catch-all" questions, "roll-up" is hard to understand

Comment: By and large I find regex's opaque so, for me (and [I'm not alone](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)), so for me a "roll up" regex answer isn't all that viable.  But what about something like [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142)?  Are you proposing that we have to answer every null reference exception question, when the answer is going to be "allocate that thing before using it"?  And every [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20940979)?  Or if not, where do you draw the line?

Comment: *suspension for subsequent violations* -- suspension **from what**?  From closing questions?  Or total suspension with a temporary rep reduction down to one?

Comment: @dbc not sure if you saw the final bullet point in the post, but that seems relevant to your question. though I agree that some spelling out of examples would be useful. see also my answer post.

Comment: I agree with the problem and the proposed solution here, but nevertheless it's still a good idea to first link to these roll-up questions as related as early as possible because typically the asker hasn't read the manual (like at all). A downvote might also still be appropriate if there is no search effort shown for example or the question is in general not so useful. Just because we don't close so many questions anymore doesn't make them better magically.

Comment: I'm in favor of this as long as it's sensibly implemented. There are some major duplicate targets in the bash tag I'd hope _don't_ get counted as rollups ([Are shell scripts sensitive to newlines and encodings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571), [I just assigned a variable but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566)) insofar as there's far less digging needed to determine how to apply their answers than there is in the "explain this regex" case, wherein the value of this rule change is hard to dispute.

Comment: Given that Stack Overflow has MILLIONS of pages to choose from.  I assume that any pages that are closed by a rollup can also be closed by a more narrow duplicate.  So, instead of reopening, eliminate the close/reopen war by adding more dupe targets or changing the solitary dupe target.  Reopening should actually be harder than closing because not only does the question need to satisfy the question posting rules, it also needs to be asking for unique resolving advice on a given topic -- very hard to do.

Comment: You need to define the term "roll-up question" better, IMHO.

Comment: "Closing this question [...] is sending a clear message to [...] OP (the polite version): 'get lost'" - that _is_ the message we should send to users asking such questions though. The issue I have with your proposal - yes rollup questions are not the best, but it's an attempt to stem the tide of crap flooding SO in absence of better tools. You propose suspending experts who try to keep the site clean while still providing OP with decent information, instead of suspending the help vampires asking such garbage or the users answering it, and without offering any other way to get rid of this crap.

Comment: @l4mpi related (deleted MSO post I wrote a year ago): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421558/11107541

Comment: I completely agree with this proposed rule. It seems that 90% of RegEx questions are lazily closed by the same three users pretty consistently (and later mercilessly deleted) and none of the dupes are helpful. I also saw a specific C++ question closed once with the target along the lines of "How do I debug small programs". Ouch, and not helpful either.

Comment: I fully support this proposal.

Comment: Support. Writing one FAQ "book", then dupehammering virtually all other questions in the tag that have a remote resemblance to it defeats the purpose of the site. It's OK to dupehammer true dupes, but only when they're actually and specifically the same question rather than some tiny fragment of a giant FAQ. The regex tag in particular has had [well-known, serious issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287/whats-up-with-the-regex-tag-it-seems-many-on-topic-regex-tag-were-removed) for awhile.

Comment: I like this idea in general. Perhaps we could get a `roll-up-Q&A` tag with it that can be applied to Q&A/wikis that are designed to catch all/catch a lot?

Comment: @TedLyngmo wouldn't that be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging#:~:text=for%20the%20question.-,Avoid%20meta%2Dtags,-Do%20not%20use)?

Comment: Surely it's a coincidence that the user who's responsible for the [vast majority of recent regex closings](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+duplicate%3Ayes) has in their bio: "If you need specific regex help that you cannot find on SO, feel free to book a 1:1 session with me...", _right_?

Comment: The Java question about null pointer exceptions is the very definition of a "roll-up" question IMO. Nobody has a problem which about null pointer exceptions, they have a specific invalid pointer access bug in their code. Reading about generic causes for null pointer exceptions is not helpful and not a duplicate. So I can't support this suggestion because the definition about what consists of a "roll-up" question is clearly subjective and we shouldn't have subjective moderation based on personal opinions.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that either clearer and more concrete conditions would make this a stronger proposal, and I also am waiting for that kind of clarification, but on the point of the Java NPE question, I'm not sure that I agree. It's a pretty small set of base causes, and I find it hard to imagine there being many more-specific setups that would be valuable to have as a dedicated Q&A aside from things like high-visibility library bugs. that's something I could not say for undefined references in C or C++ builds.

Comment: @Lundin If someone _really_ puts in the effort to create an MRE of a Java NPE, I'd imagine most of the time it'd become an instance of one of the listed causes in the Java NPE Q&A, and it doesn't take scrolling through potentially several pages of answers to find that cause listed in that Q&A, which is also something I can't really say for the C/C++ undefined reference Q&A.

Comment: @Lundin The Java NPE canonical is the only reasonable way to handle all the questions by people who ask for help with NPEs without apparently understanding what they mean. There is no point having specific answers to point out a specific line of code; what's needed is to explain the nature of the problem and how to address it in a way that is useful to future visitors. That's the NPE canonical.

Comment: A Java NPE is also (I'm pretty sure) a lot easier to debug than an undefined reference error (my understanding is that those are hard for tools to give good diagnostics for by nature of the C/C++ build model). The Java NPE Q&A has the luxury of being able to describe how to read a stacktrace, instead of going through a bunch of different build scenarios and making essentially a bunch of "check that you didn't do X1, X2,... XN wrong".

Comment: @khelwood "There is no point having specific answers to point out a specific line of code" Actually, one of the core purposes of SO is trouble-shooting/debugging of specific code. SO is mainly a debugging site. That's usually the one thing that all users agree on as on-topic. When it comes to more fuzzy stuff like "the purpose of SO is building a library of knowledge", then there is far less consensus.

Comment: This happened to the pygame tag. Most posts there are closed by random duplicates that may or may not be related. It's sad.

Comment: One word "Amen". Much better roll-up policy than current for the exact reason stated, roll-up questions, no matter how good, do not cover all cases.

Comment: I'll call out [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) as a really bad example of this.  The question is too broad and locked for historical significance.  However, it has been used as a dup target.  Many of the linked questions aren't even well answered by it.  In some cases they aren't answered by it at all.

Comment: @jedwards, just to be clear, you are rallying for not closing regex questions as duplicates at all, not closing them by mentioned user, or for them to delete "offending" phrase from bio? Also, I fail to see how this is related to proposed rule: it doesn't prohibit goldtaggers from using their dupe-hammer in general, only for very specific targets. (Just a little hint: mentioned user closed over last year more than 400 questions in regex, and only 10 as a duplicate of reference)

Comment: @khelwood "There is no point having specific answers to point out a specific line of code; what's needed is to explain the nature of the problem ..." Hmmm, countless answers to countless questions indeed point out a specific line of code. There is a point in doing that. But it's also useful to generalize and explain the nature of the problem. Sometimes I want my car fixed and sometimes I want to learn about Newtonian mechanics. This site does both and it's all a big grey area. This question better defines the term "roll-up question" more or it will lead to further issues down the road.

Comment: I understand what I'm about to say is off-topic, but honestly, in the modern world, almost every "What does this Regex mean?" question would probably be better off forwarded to ChatGPT4.0. ChatGPT4.0 is AMAZING at translating regex to English, much better than most humans.

Comment: There's a lot of answer and comments here, so maybe I've missed it; however, would it be possible (or desirable) to have a "Moderator note" on these common roll-up (and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/10871073)) dupe targets. Seems only right if the use of such would result in potential suspensions.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm assuming you mean a "post notice"? If so, you have my +1. especially since Machiavity says that the list of such questions is small.

Comment: @starball Yeah, I think that's what it's called. A purpose-made blue banner (like that for a protected question) would be nice but would need devs to write the code for it. In the meantime, a mod-added text 'header' may suffice.

Answer (score 98):

> "Figure out what, in this giant pile of information, answers your question."
> That's not useful.

Exactly. Yes, we should all Read The Fine Manual. But if the OP didn't already RTFM, throwing yet another manual at them isn't going to improve matters. And if they *did* read the manual but are a bit overwhelmed & confused, a giant info-dump is likely to compound the confusion & increase the anxiety.

If the OP asked a clear and  specific (i.e., well-scoped) question they need and deserve some clear and specific guidance.

I have no objection to those giant roll-up Q&As, per se, but I've never thought they make good dupe targets. They are useful repositories of more specific questions, and those specific questions should be used by the Subject Matter Experts as the actual dupe targets. The roll-up question can be linked in an "Also See" comment, or added as an *additional* dupe target by a gold badger or mod. But to use the roll-up as the primary dupe target is just cruel.

If the OP submitted a low quality no-effort question which is not clear and specific, we can close it for other reasons. We don't really *want* it to survive as a dupe because it's *not* a useful signpost.

Comment: I always find the word "specific" tricky. it's ambiguous between at least two meanings: "well-scoped" vs. "localized". my general understanding has been "well-scoped" (Ex. I spent some time debugging my problem in my project to create a MRE) => good!, "very localized" (here's a code dump of my project- where's the bug?) => not so good. could you clarify what you mean when you say "specific"?

Comment: @starball I meant "well-scoped".

Comment: thanks. that was all I was waiting for to smash that like button.

Comment: This is a good point, closing against a more specific link included in the roll-up isn't too much to ask.

Comment: "Read The Fine Manual".  Are we not allowed to use the F-word here, when it is part of a well known expression?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock We are supposed to use Safe For Work language on SE sites, and to avoid the use of swear words, unless the word is an unavoidable part of the question or answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/334566 Also note that Machavity's question uses "fine": *What these roll-ups have become, in essence, is another "fine" manual for users to read.*

Comment: If the OP didn't put any effort into researching their question, I don't think we should put much effort into identifying a duplicate that specifically addresses the OP's scenario. Any duplicate that points the OP in the right direction should suffice, whether that's a roll-up or not.

Comment: I like your point on signposts. If your end goal is to delete the bad question, then don't dupe VTC it because a dupe VTC is saying you think its a helpful question (ie, as a signpost) and therefore ineligible for deletion.

Comment: I asked one Regex question that was obviously not a duplicate of the one it was closed for… and the person it was closed *by* offers on his profile paid regex consulting, “if you can't find an answer on stack overflow”—might be worth looking into conflict of interest on the power users?

Comment: @James That user was mentioned earlier in this comment on the question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427530/rule-proposal-duplicate-closure-to-roll-up-questions-is-no-longer-allowed/427540?noredirect=1#comment982218_427530

Comment: Is it possible to deep link a dupe-ish question to a portion of an answer in a roll-up? If so, maybe the rule would be only close as a dupe if it can directly reference something that actually answers the specific question.

Comment: @acjay No, you can't link to a section within an answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/334566

Answer (score 35):

I do think some dup targets that I've seen before (and I'll admit have even used once or twice in a way that I currently question) are kind of collapsing / have collapsed upon themselves. Some that make me think "wait- I thought SO was to make it so people can come with a specific (well scoped)<sup>1</sup> question and not have to sift through a bunch of text to get the answer to their specific question".

To people who think closing as a duplicate of these "catch-all" / "reference" questions is fine, here's a challenge: See also [the MSE FAQ post on duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/997587), which links to [this blog post by Joel Spolsky written all the way back in 2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20going%20to%20close%20a%20user%27s%20question%20as%20a%20duplicate%2C%20it%20has%20to%20be%20a%20real%20duplicate.):

> **If you're going to close a user's question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate**. For example, if a user asks, "What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?" it's OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like "What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?" But it's not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks. That's the moral equivalent of saying "[RTFM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM)." Stack Overflow is not meant to be a library of reference manuals. It's supposed to contain the same *information* as a library of reference manuals, in the form of millions of questions and answers. Combined with Google, that gives us the magical power of a library of reference manuals you never have to read! It's like, you got to the library, and there's a wizard there at the door, and you ask your question, and, instead of being told to read a book, you just got (are you sitting down?) *the actual answer*!

I've been thinking about this for a while but had been too lazy and scared to bring it up. Actually, I [*had* sort of posted about this kind of topic a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421558/11107541), but deleted that post.

---

The one particular one that comes to mind right now (with no disrespect to the people who have contributed to it) is [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/11107541). I think "what is an undefined/unresolved reference" by itself is a fine and *extremely* useful SO question to have, but "how do I fix it" (or "how do I find out why *exactly* it's happening *in my type of setup*") is too much for a single Q&A to handle. There are just too many possible reasons- each that have causes that are common enough that having dedicated Q&A would be more useful. I *do* think having some sort of aggregation of links to Q&A for specific, common causes is a useful thing, but [this specific way of going about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/11107541) with the links being to individual answer posts under *the same question*, each for a different possible cause indicates that something is wrong with the way SO is being used here. I'd imagine a better scenario would be to have

- one Q&A for what an undefined reference error is and why it happens *in general*,
- one community wiki Q&A for what common *specific / in-context* causes are, with an answer linking to

  - individual Q&A for those specific / in-context causes, and how to fix those individual problems.

An example of the community wiki collection of links to specific Q&A would be [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/11107541). Possibly ironically and sadly, that question is the top-5th duplicate target (counting by duplicates that are non-deleted).

What would one do instead of closing as a duplicate of that "table of contents / list of common reasons" question if one sees a question that is caused by *multiple* specific problems and one doesn't have a gold badge to close as a duplicate of multiple specific Q&A? Close as needing focus? Answer? Downvote and move on?

---

I think it might also be useful to spell things out clearly for some of the top duplicate targets. I wrote a SEDE query a year ago that could be useful: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1673806/top-dup-targets. Here are some particular ones I'm interested in:

- [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/11107541)
- [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/11107541)
- [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/11107541)
- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/11107541) (already explicitly used as poster child in proposal post)
- [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/11107541)
- [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706216/11107541)
- [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/11107541)
- [Reference Guide: What does this symbol mean in PHP? (PHP Syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/11107541) (already explicitly used as poster child in proposal post)
- [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/11107541)
- [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/11107541)
- [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/11107541)

---

<sup>1: I always find the word "specific" tricky. It's ambiguous between at least two meanings: "well-scoped" vs. "localized". My general understanding has been "well-scoped" (Ex. I spent some time debugging my problem in my project to create a MRE) => good!, "very localized" (here's a code dump of my project- where's the bug?) => not so good. In this post, when I say "specific", I am referring to "well-scoped".</sup>

Comment: "[*What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) "should never be used as a duplicate target, it's a list of dupe targets maintained in a wiki answer.

Comment: "[*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959)" is not a roll-up question, it's one very specific issue, very much like the Java null-pointer-exception one.

Comment: Does this mean that the super-canonical on sorting by @deceze is a rollup? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/2943403)  It single-handedly covers dozens of topics.

Comment: @Bergi if it shouldn't be used as a dupe target, it should have resided on the tag wiki. (And before you say that the tag wiki is poorly discoverable, read Shog about tag wiki's)

Answer (score 17):

Good to see that y'all [are looking into this now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421392/please-stop-deleting-our-content-without-coherent-reasons-regex-tag/421397#comment933492_421397).  And it's good to see that it's being applied in a more broad standard, rather than just in a singular instance.

This is the first step though; people will still want some kind of canonical to catch all of the whack-a-mole questions they get from a subject that has a lot of surface area, like regexes.  The next step would be to get some buy-in on what constitutes a sensible canonical for questions like this.

Comment: _"on what constitutes a sensible canonical for questions like this."_ You're not suggesting to replace one broad canonical with another, are you?

Comment: @Cerbrus: No, that would be backwards.  What I was thinking was that there be some kind of discussion/standard on when a canonical should be applied vs when it shouldn't.

Comment: A canonical question is a question that presents a single problem and that all potential solutions are posted there. Every question is a canonical of the problem presented in the question. We do not need a question tier other than "should be answered or not".

Answer (score 16):

**Not all (uses of) catch-all duplicate targets are bad.** They are sometimes abused, but a blanket ban is too much. If we want to regulate their use, we need a more involved rule than just "catch-all duplicates bad". But I'm not yet sure what the exact rule should be.

Some thoughts:

- **Ok for trivial questions**. If a user clearly didn't bother reading the manual, using a manual-like duplicate target is fine.

  For example, if a user asks *"what does `^` do in regex"*, I don't see an issue with [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/2752075) being used as a dupe target.

  This is arguably *better* than finding a more specific dupe target, because we want them to be able to find this information on their own. We don't want them to come back and ask about `*`, `{}`, `[]`, and every other symbol they see next (for us to find duplicates for them); we want them to go read the manual, be it our manual-like dupe target or something else.
- **Bad for complex questions**.

  I sometimes see [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2752075) being abused like this.

  This error can be caused by a basic lack of understanding of the compilation process, then this duplicate target is fine.

  But it can also be caused by hard-to-diagnose issues (like messing up the compiler flag order in a subtle way, or downloading libraries for a different flavor of the compiler), then the duplicate target is completely useless. The asker has near zero chances of finding the correct solution among the 48 answers to that question.
- **Is the dupe target easy to navigate?**

  If the user asks about basic regex syntax, they can easily find the symbol they're interested in in [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/2752075).

  If the user asks about an `undefined reference` error, it can be difficult for them to navigate [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2752075), because this error has several different causes, all of which produce very similar error messages, and the huge dupe target lacks any organization.

  If they're dealing with the most common case, good, they'll find the explanation at the top of the first answer. If not, they're likely screwed.
- **"List of books" as a dupe target is passive-aggressive if OP didn't ask about books.**

  This probably goes without saying, but using [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2752075) as the duplicate target for basic C++ questions (as opposed to requests for books) is outright passive-aggressive, and shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: I don't really agree with the first point, if you really want to point them to a manual you can post a separate comment for that. If something is on-topic and not a duplicate of another specific question I don't see why we should close it as a duplicate of a "roll-up" question. In this case the example you give does have a specific duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908725/what-do-and-mean-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Why does it matter in this case if we close as a dupe of the "roll-up" question or a more specific question? It's trivial to find the latter from the former. Arguably the former sends a better message (that SO is not a substitute for doing minimal prior research).

Comment: If you are looking to imply any message the simplest way to get that across is to state the very thing. You might assume that closing as a duplicate of that kind of question sends across the message you are looking to send but that is not necessarily the case. If you are looking to send any message other than "this question is already asked and answer here" by closing as duplicate IMO you are attributing a wrong purpose to the duplicate closures.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat *"simplest way to get that across is to state the very thing"* This doesn't work with human beings, sadly. If you see a homework question, tell them to not ask such questions again, but also give the solution, the message you got across is "yes, you can ask this stuff here".

Comment: Then why do you assume the closure you speak of will get the message that you intend to across to them? Downvote their question if it lacks research (It is there in the tooltip), eventually they'll get a question ban and that will stop them.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Because, again, if you give them a reference to check for the future related issues (such as a list of regex features with explanations), they will just use that the next time instead of asking you. But if you instead give them a specific duplicate (e.g. about a single regex feature), they won't know how to find Q&As about other related topics, and will come back to you again for you to find the dupes for them.

Comment: As I mentioned before you can link the reference to them in a comment, something like "You might also find [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) useful for understanding a specific piece of regex syntax. Please refer to it and search for any existing duplicates before asking a new question"

Comment: "We don't want them to come back and ask about *, {}, [], and every other symbol they see next (for us to find duplicates for them); we want them to go read the manual, be it our manual-like dupe target or something else." - They might do it anyway, even though they were already shown the guide; and if they are downvoted and pointed at specific canonicals each time, then that is quick, clear action that complies with policy in every imaginable way and also gets a problematic user swiftly Q-banned. I see no downsides.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The only downside is that we have to find the specific duplicates ourselves. But I think I agree now, if this is the price of preventing dupehammer abuse, this is ok.

Comment: "For example, if a user asks "what does ^ do in regex"" - the problem is, questions like this are rare. The common case is "how do I write a regex to do XYZ" (far too broad, just as it would be for any other programming language; but people don't properly treat embedded DSLs as programming languages in their own right) or else "what's wrong with my regex" (often without even trying to explain the desired spec).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel So what's the correct response to those? Close as too broad/lacking details? Closing as a dupe of regex reference is probably not good?

Comment: As too broad, yes. At least as things currently stand.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Agreed. This is more or less what I wanted to express with the last bullet.

Answer (score 15):

Will closure of *any* question as duplicate of mentioned roll-ups be prohibited?

And if yes, based on mentioned [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), what should happen to questions that look something like following?

> I was given this legacy project, and it has this regex that I can't understand
>
> ```
> <some regex>
> ```

---

Also, roll-up seems to be somewhat questionable term. In the interest of transparency, if this rule should be accepted, there must be clearly defined list of roll-ups not-to-be-used for hammering.

Comment: Why would such a question need dupe closure at all? In other tags, "what does <chunk of code>" mean must be very explicit about which part needs explanation and why, otherwise it lacks details and focus.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, that is a good point, thanks for explanation! It seems like I'm so used to how things are, that I forgot how they should be)

Comment: While I support the sentiment of closing as needs focus versus a "broad-sweeping-mega-canonical", I'd like to season the discussion with the fact that closing with a dupe is ALWAYS more insightful than closing as any other reason.  I mean, closing as a non-duplicate says: "your question doesn't qualify"; whereas closing as a duplicate says: "You can find what you need by reading this page".

Comment: @mickmackusa, you are raising interesting perspective. Additionally, why its unpleasant together your post closed with reference to loads of text, I'd argue closing it as "you have a bad question" without any reference is worse. This might need more consideration in terms of "toxicity" and general reputation of the site. Consider posting a separate answer for better visibility

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don’t see a better quality in “Needs more focus” as a close reason. This reason has been abused as generic close reason as much as “Duplicate”. The deeper problem has been hinted in the question: “*…as much as it sends another message moderators have been fighting against for years: RTFM*” The moderators do not want such questions to be closed at all, they want to force the community to answer such low quality questions, by removing the appropriate close reasons. The community reacts by using other, inappropriate close reasons instead. This fight will have no winners.

Comment: @Holger The better quality in "Needs more focus" as a close reason is *that it actually applies* to questions that need focus. Still, if a question doesn't need focus, don't close it with that reason. Just as if a question is not a duplicate, don't close it it with that reason either. An "RTFM question" in itself isn't in need of closure and people who think otherwise should RTFSOM.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The “Needs more focus” reason provides the following explanation right beneath it: “*This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*” So how is a question like “Explain this RegEx to me” asking multiple questions at once or not focusing on one problem? Face it, you provided a text book example of stretching the rules trying to find a close reason for something this site doesn’t provide a close reason for (anymore). In other words, an “Explain this RegEx to me” is of the same category as “RTFM question” which should not be closed.

Comment: @Holger "Still, if a question doesn't need focus, don't close it with that reason." You might also want to reread my initial comment, which *doesn't* say you necessarily have to use the needs more focus close reason.

Comment: IMO the regex community on SO is pretty awful (almost all of them get mercilessly dupehammered and deleted even if they have helpful answers). Regex should follow the same rules as the other tags: if its overly broad close it as such and if you want to point them in the right direction just comment a link to a guide (like what you linked in your answer). You can't dupe close to a guide because a guide is not a question; its a guide. I think a good number of dupehammer-holders consider their dupe hammer to be instant closing powers when it really should only be used on actual dupes.

Comment: @MichaelM., if nothing else, I very much agree with your last sentence. And proposed rule seems to have as it's goal exactly that: to remind dupehammer-holders not to abuse it.

Comment: @MichaelM. regarding overzealous closures in regex, IMO it's way better to have that, than what is happening in sql, for example, where seemingly every question is answered. At least in terms of declared goal of creating knowledge library, that is. But this is probably a discussion for other time and place.

Answer (score 9):

No, the problem is that different gold-badge users in a specific tag are having question closure/reopening fights. This is trivially fixed by having a nice chat with the one who is violating rules around question quality by reopening rubbish questions, and if they don't desist, giving them a vacation from the site. That's a moderator job, not a curator job.

> Duplicate closure like this is basically throwing a volume of information at users and telling them "Figure out what, in this giant pile of information, answers your question." That's not useful.

Do you know what else is not useful? Users who post low-quality questions that fail to do absolutely trivial research. Those questions have zero value to Stack Overflow as a concept of a high-quality repository of questions and answers.

> this is why we can't have nice things.

Asinine policies like this allow rubbish questions to stay open for no good reason. *That* is why we can't have nice things. *That* is why curators are no longer curating. *That* is why Stack Overflow is dying.

Stop trying to make it more difficult to get rid of the rubbish. Stop making this site into a one-stop shop for help vampires.

Comment: duplicate closure doesn't "get rid" of a rubbish question. in fact, duplicate closure blocks out several conditions for [roomba](/help/roomba) to more thoroughly get rid of something, leaving deletion to the much smaller (compared to the pool of people who can downvote) pool of people who can del-vote. I wish I could say downvote and move on (and let roomba clean up) and that that would be enough, but peoples' definition of "rubbish" don't align, and one person's rubbish is sometimes another person's opportunity to make some easy rep from getting an accept (both which can also block roomba).

Comment: @starball in my view, a duplicate that acts as an adequate signpost for a useful canonical, has already been dealt with by the closure, even if it's otherwise low quality. Some attempts at canonicals are too broad, and some questions closed to them are terrible signposts (e.g. because the title is garbage or OP, as we used to say, "lacks minimal understanding"). That's a different matter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel re: "_because the title is garbage_" (in which case what follows in the body is usually not that great either), that is an example of what I was so lovingly attempting to express above that I would like to be handled by downvotes and roomba. the quality of a title is extremely important. bad/misleading title staying up as a signpost is detrimental to the experience of people searching for an answer on search engines. it misleads and wastes the searcher's time.

Comment: I find that often the Roomba is blocked more so by the answers (when an answer wasn't necessary/suitable) versus the kind of closure that was eventually used.  Rush answers to pages that should have been closed instead is a persistent problem.

Answer (score 9):

I hesitantly support the spirit of this proposal, but I think it needs nuance. I hope I can offer yet another perspective.

I use [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) as a canonical for "how do I troubleshoot `cron` jobs". (I don't have a gold badge in the [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) tag, but I do have one in several related tags, such as [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)). This may not be a common FAQ as such, but a large number of "halp, my `cron` job is not working" questions do not have any details, and so pointing them to a troubleshooting guideline seems useful, especially when the new question is not so much.

I generally try to find the time to also add a comment to tell them that their question can be reopened if they can update their question to include enough details to make it useful and well-defined.

The canonical I found is dubious for several reasons, though.

- It's about a fairly specific problem, and tangentially about Python.
- It's slightly hard to find in search because the title uses the odd and ugly intercap compound "CronJob" as a single word (I mean *I* can find it, but it's perhaps not reasonable to expect the OP to have found it before asking).
- It has obviously grown organically over time, so the exposition is not particularly good as a guideline.
- Like many popular questions, it has multiple low-quality answers which worked for a single user or a small group of users, but do not explain why it worked or under what circumstances it would.

I'm providing this background to suggest that the specifics of the canonical can also play a role in deciding when it is acceptable to hammer. Especially if the warts of this canonical could be removed, I think it makes sense to continue to hammer questions which are easily solved by these instructions, complex as they may be. Having one canonical for each case seems excessive (especially when many of the error cases involve system administration rather than programming, and would thus be off-topic for Stack Overflow in isolation).

Comment: I guess "_halp, my cron job is not working_" can be interpreted as "My Cron Job is not working and I have no idea how to debug it, what steps can I take to figure this issue out?" I don't really see a problem closing that with the duplicate target you mention as otherwise the question would mostly just be closed for lacking details. I don't really think this is the type of question this proposal is talking about when it says "roll-up" questions though, but I do agree some more clarity on that would be useful.

Comment: Such duplicate closures in my opinion would actually be quite useful since it then allows the user to find out more details and craft a better question if needed. Sharing all those debugging steps over comments probably won't work as well.

Comment: If the question is vague and low-quality, sure, it can be helpful to point the OP to a generic "how to" tutorial. But that can be done with a comment. I disagree with using the dupe-hammer just to quickly close such questions. As I said at the end of my answer, we only want dupes to survive if they're useful signposts. Otherwise, close it for lacking details / focus (and possibly downvote), so it will be auto-deleted by the Roomba in due course.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, very similar interpretation can justify closure of "Halp, I don't know what this regex does" as "I have regex, and I don't know even where/how to start to figure this out". And proposed rules seems to be very specifically against it.

Comment: @markalex that is a valid point you have there, best simply close as lacking focus / lacking details whichever makes sense then. An extra comment pointing to these questions can be added if needed.

Comment: @PM2Ring I would be on your side if "closing for lacking details/focus" didn't require a distributed effort among multiple people, in an environment where people are explicitly incentivized to just write a low-quality answer instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's a valid point, but it only takes 2 other close voters. And hopefully, if the question does attract a low quality answer that answer won't get upvoted, blocking Roomba. The OP is *supposed* to improve the details / focus of their closed question, and although that's pretty rare, it does happen (especially adding MRE-ish code). IME, it's even more rare for a dupe-closed question to be edited to properly explain why the dupe target doesn't adequately cover it.

Comment: (cont) However, I fully agree that the environment *should* be incentivizing people to write answers and questions that are welcome additions to our Q&A collection.

Comment: "And hopefully, if the question does attract a low quality answer that answer won't get upvoted" - I have found that the sort of people who look at close-worthy questions without immediately taking action, and then also look at the answers, have depressingly low standards for answers.

Comment: Don't questions about cron belong on Super User or Unix & Linux nowadays? (Assuming it isn't about writing or modifying the code for cron, of course.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton There are a lot which are off-topic indeed; though also many about a shell scripting (or Python etc) problem where running out of `cron` is one aspect of the problem statement.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly the question can be boiled down to:

> (...) using a single roll-up question as the duplicate target.
>
> A prime example would be [this regex roll-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

I think it's reasonable to ask a dupehammer close voter to choose a specific question from the list instead of just closing against the roll-up thread itself. So yes I think this rule should be enforced.

Comment: see my answer post at "_What would one do instead of closing as a duplicate of that "table of contents / list of common reasons" question if_"

Answer (score 7):

I agree with this initiative in principle.

When I hammer a page that has been answered by one or more users, I often ask answerers to transfer their insights to the dupe target because [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:%7E:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

When a narrow question is closed by a broad dupe target, often it is non-trivial/unsuitable to transfer the narrow insights. Adding insights to a rollup can be less attractive because it might be an unrewarding wiki-edit, or be an answer which gets lost in the flood of other answers.

- (asker win) The asker and future readers receive narrow resolving advice. The argument of returning the same low-effort advice for a low-effort question ignores the fact that future readers will be leveraging this page. We must always give our best advice no matter how lame the question.
- (answerer win) Contributors who wish to share their insights will be able to see if they have unique insights to add to Stack Overflow and they will see where to post them. Contributors are not silenced.

---

Most of the (PHP) pages that I close (which were posted after 2015) are usually closable by at least 5 different pages.  It takes more effort to hunt for multiple duplicates, but I believe this to be the most generous form of closure that there is and everybody wins.

Multi-closing:

- Reduces the likelihood of close/reopen wars because reopen voters have a harder time disproving all of the dupe targets' validity.
- Helps to link related content, and simplifies the job of nominating new canonicals.
- Indicates to the asker that they should have searched for other keywords or, more likely, just searched more.
- Is definitive proof that the page is a good candidate for deletion because it is an nth dupe on a given topic.

Comment: Sadly, non-gold-badge-holders can't perform multi-target closure (at least not unilaterally--they can achieve it indirectly with another close voter's and Community's help).

Comment: In the worst case, a forest of "did you also consider" dupe links will (rightfully IMHO) feel to the asker like an insult. Two or three dupes is fine, but more than that looks like obfuscation; and then the question should probably be closed as "needs focus" instead, anyway. The specificity of the dupes also matters; two links which each points to a grab bag of dozens of speculative answers is already too much.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this - it's better to find a more specific duplicate where possible (vs. what amounts to a RTFM closure, which was no longer a valid reason after the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason went away). However, the two cases where I think that this *should* be allowed are:

- Where the OP clearly put forth zero prior debugging or problem-solving effort, or where it's trivially solvable on their own if they use the right technique. For example, if the problem could be trivially solvable by stepping through the code with a debugger, I might point them to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).
- Where the same or very similar questions have been asked and answered many times before, such as debugging a NullPointerException. In those cases, it's hard to imagine what we could possibly add to the literally thousands of times it's been asked before.

Comment: 1) "_I might point them to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)_" uhhhhhhhhhh, you mean in a comment and not as a dup-vote, right? see also [this deleted post of mine](/a/421558/11107541) and the question it answers. 2) "_such as debugging a NullPointerException_" read the proposal post, which literally says: "_So [this Java question about null pointer exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) does not qualify, as it is about a single topic._"

Answer (score -19):

I will just say this although some may disagree - any time you make it harder for a user to find the answer they are seeking, you encourage them to go to another site that will not make it difficult to get an answer.  And for the past year or so, that other site has likely been one where an AI answers any questions put to it, such as ChatGPT or Phind or Bing's AI.  Yes, it may hallucinate an answer, but then any given answer you get here may not work either.  An AI-driven site won't tell you to read a manual, or someone's long boring FAQ, or a document written by a programmer that has no idea how to write so that their document can be understood by mere users.  It will just try to answer your question, and not berate you or tell you that you're lazy or close your question without answering it (well, unless maybe you are asking it to tell you something that has been deemed harmful or sensitive information).

It is the premature closing of user questions that is killing sites like this, since users can so easily turn to an AI-driven site and just get the information they are seeking, or some approximation of it.  And while AI still gives a lot of incorrect answers, it is getting better and will probably continue to give increasingly accurate answers.  For the same reason that people pretty much stopped using printed encyclopedias once Wikipedia became available, people will stop using sites such as this if there are easier ways to get answers (and never even a hint of attitude for asking a newbie question, or the closing of a question that a user spent considerable time and effort typing out).

So, I not only support your proposal, but in my opinion questions should not be closed as duplicates unless they are the exact duplicate of a question that's been asked previously (I don't mean the words have to be exactly the same, but it has to be the same question).  And a user asking a specific question should never be referred to a "catch-all" document; that's just an invitation for them to go elsewhere.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I think "killing the site" is a bit overboard. I'd been concerned about [the drop in traffic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387278/997587), but these days, [I see the decline in traffic more optimistically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384378/997587). I think there are a lot of low quality question posts that get closed as duplicates inappropriately, but that doesn't mean I'm eager to see them being posted at all either.

Comment: I think the last paragraph has some merit, but the berating and frankly very one-sided first two paragraphs that don't seem to add anything to the specific issue just drown that. Please consider to [edit] the answer to remove or at least tone down its "introduction" and focus on the last one, which desperately needs fleshing out. As you've admitted right away, "exact duplicate" isn't feasible but an infodump isn't either, so where should the line be drawn?

Comment: "any time you make it harder for a user to find the answer they are seeking, you encourage them to go to another site that will not make it difficult to get an answer." - has it occurred to you that when someone closes your question as a duplicate, **that is giving you an answer**? Possibly multiple answers - i.e., all the ones already written on the duplicate question.