# Why was my question upvoted, but my self-answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, downvote-reason

Two years ago, I had a specific question regarding creating a CLI application. I could not find a solution to my problem on Google Search (now the top result seems to be my question), so I drafted a question on Stack Overflow.

Before I posted my question, I spent a bit more time fiddling around with APIs and found a solution for myself. According to the advice at [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow), I was under the impression that it is valuable to the site to add information I wish I had found earlier. Therefore, I posted [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73194349/16781396) and [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73194350/16781396). When some time had passed without another answer, I pressed the accept button on my answer.

The question received an upvote. The answer, which as far as I can tell is clear and effective, received 2 downvotes. It later received an upvote, I think it was a few months later.

What may have happened?

I don't care about reputation on this site—I rarely use Stack Overflow these days. I'm just curious if I did something wrong.

If I did, how can I fix my mistake?

Comment: Why? Someone liked the question, and someone (perhaps someone *else*) didn't like the answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I only ask this because the answer received two downvotes, not just one. If it were only one I would think nothing of it.

Comment: But how is anyone but the voter themself going to know *why* they  voted the way that they did? I'm dead serious with this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's a good point. I guess I'm not really asking *why* it was downvoted, more so about why the behavior of answering my own (admittedly basic) question wasn't received well. Maybe I'm looking into it to deep and it was just a bad answer for some other reason I'm not seeing, but that's at least my perception. (P.S. love your username)

Comment: "about why the behavior of answering my own (admittedly basic) question wasn't received well" Why would you think that is an issue? (Rhetorical.) You are not looking "too deep, you are jumping to conclusions. There's nothing wrong with self-answers per se. We *don't know* why there were downvotes. Or upvotes or novotes.

Comment: Not the voter, but the parts about `__dirname` feel like tangential rambling but make up a huge part of the answer. Consider just the trailing comment in the code block (why isn’t that regular text?!?) which takes up three times more volume for the `__dirname` part than the proper way of doing things.

Comment: I don't know about the downvote reason but your question is basically a duplicate, you might not have found the relevant question(s) because you seem to be focusing the question on "relative path as CLI input" when it's really two different questions being "How to take command line arguments?" and "How to convert relative path to absolute path?"

Comment: *"What may have happened?"* - the site is being used as intended? The "why was my question upvoted" part of the title is really a red herring, it has nothing to do with your question. It boils down to this being a typical "why was my question/answer downvoted" question. If you are going to follow tradition, you follow that up with "Why isn't it mandatory to explain downvotes?" I wouldn't though, it has been asked and answered enough times now.

Answer (score 6):

> now the top result seems to be my question

**What search terms did you use?**

The *question* is about converting relative paths to absolute in Node. If I put `node.js convert relative path to absolute` into a search engine (not even Google), the first result I get is [the duplicate your question was linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829118) - it happens to be an exact title match, because someone had the foresight to title the question exactly the way that a shrewd web searcher would phrase the query. It was asked many years before your Q&A, so it should have been findable for you at the time. Similarly, I also get results like [Nodejs get absolute path relative to process.cwd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658611) and [Converting an absolute path to a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438689) (the other way around). If I scroll through for things off-site that are explicitly marked as published before your Q&A, I find e.g. https://medium.com/beqode/absolute-vs-relative-import-paths-nodejs-1e4efa65a7bb.

It seems like you imagined, at the time, that "even if the Node script is being run from a different directory than it is in?" represents an additional complication - but it really does not. It does, however, introduce an ambiguity: any relative path needs to be relative *to* something. "How do I convert a path that's relative to the CWD to an absolute path?" is different from "how do I convert a path that's relative to the script's directory, to an absolute path?".

But either of those in turn is trivial - what you're *really* asking is how to *determine the path* to which you will make the relative path, relative. Those are separate, straightforward questions which presumably have their own duplicates:

- [How do I get the path to the current script with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243)
- [Getting directory from which node.js was executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149274) (perhaps someone else can find something more authoritative; I don't normally look at JavaScript questions)

along with a lot of ancillary info or repackagings of the essential question, such as

- [process.env.PWD vs process.cwd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414852/)
- [What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874382)

---

> The question received an upvote. The answer, which as far as I can tell is clear and effective, received 2 downvotes. It later received an upvote, I think it was a few months later.

Obviously, I can't go back in time (it's only been a year and 4 months, btw) and read the mind of people whose identity I didn't know. But I agree with these actions.

Your question is a fine signpost (although based on how you answered it, it seems like you considered that the *main* difficulty was better addressed by a different duplicate target; but people who find this question with a search engine IMO won't see it that way).

The answer is redundant, and its existence prevents signed-out users from being automatically redirected to the canonical.

---

Ideally, IMHO, there would be a single "managing relative and absolute paths in Node" canonical that covered these topics, like "how can I convert between absolute and relative paths?" with a single that explains that relative paths need a reference point, and then shows the few most common reference points. While we're [currently trying to outlaw dupe closures to "roll-up" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427530/), I think these issues are closely enough related that explaining them in one place makes far more sense, and does not represent a lack of focus. For what it's worth, I have had similar frustrations with closing duplicates of the analogous questions in the Python tag.

If you told us that your question had been intended as an attempt at such - I think it missed the mark.

(In the comments, Abdul Aziz Barkat pointed out that your version of the question **also** talks about taking in command-line input. This aspect is *clearly* unrelated, and would be out of scope for any canonical - but I assume that you didn't really see it as an *essential* aspect of your question, since you didn't actually *explain* the use of `argv[2]` in your answer.)

Comment: Not sure it matters at this point but I don't think the core of the problem was relative/absolute paths, it was the use of `process.cwd()` which I didn't know about until I wrote the answer. In hindsight you are correct that it is a dupe though I'm not sure that it's the dupe of the question it was closed as.

Comment: Do any of the links I offered here look like a better duplicate?